# Booststrap popover on select option tag example is not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, hover, html-select

I have requirement that I have to show **each option title** on mouse over. 
Bootstrap popover is working for the other text fields in the same form but is not working for the dropdown.

I tried title attibute on each option, it is working in chrome but in IE hover text not showing long enough time, So I decided to use Bootstrap.

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div>
<select id="testList">
<option value="1" title="Header1" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" style="color:red;">Item 1</option>
<option value="2" title="Header2" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover"style="color:green;">Item 2</option>
<option value="3" title="Header3" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover"style="">Item 3</option>
<option value="4" title="Header4" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" style="color:orange;">Item 4</option>
</select>

</div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();   
});


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here I can't use size attribute on select tag

Could anyone figure out the reason for not working

or

Could some one give me the code example to show each option value on mouse hover.it can be either tooltip or popover.

Answer (score 0):

We have to tweak a little bit to make it work. We can't directly add a pop over to select option. Instead we can apply chosen plugin on select box, it converts the select options to unordered list. on top of that we can add pop over on each li element.

```
$("#testList").chosen({                    
                    disable_search: true

});

$("testList_chosen.li.active-result").each(function(){
                $(this).attr('data-toggle','popover');
});

$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({container: 'body'});
```

Read more about chosen plug in here. http://julesjanssen.github.io/chosen/